# oAuth2 web request works in browser but not in app

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, xamarin.forms

I have the following code sample with which I'm trying to authenticate an Azure active directory user within a Xamarin forms app

The URL (I've removed the actual client ID) works fine in a browser but fails when trying to send the http request

The error message says 'the response type must include client_id'

```
            string URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
                        + "client_id=xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx"
                        + "&response_type=code"
                        + "&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"
                        + "&response_mode=query"
                        + "&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read"
                        + "&state=12345";



            var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;

            System.Console.WriteLine(URL);

            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                webRequest.Timeout = 20000;

                webRequest.ContentType = "text/html";
                //POST the data.
                using (requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    requestWriter.Write(postData);
                }
            }

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);

            ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

You put parameters in the URL, so you need to use GET method, instead of POST (like your browser does when you paste the URL in its address bar).

So, replace:

```
webRequest.Method = "POST";
```

by:

```
webRequest.Method = "GET";
```

and remove:

```
//POST the data.
using (requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
  {
    requestWriter.Write(postData);
  }
```

Comment: If I do that I get an error message "Cannot send data when method is GET"

Comment: remove the 3 lines after `// POST the data`. It is useless since it is a GET method. This explains your error message.